# Can you redirect output of a process on one system to a file on another system?

Tags: linux, redirection

I have a coworker who was gripping the log file on one system, redirecting the output into a file, and then using `sftp` to put the file on a server. He asked if it was possible to simply redirect his output directly to another system.

I tried various ideas using `scp`:

```
$ cat .profile | scp qazwart@server2   # Nope didn't work
$ cat .profile | scp - qazwart@serer2  # Told me "-" doesn't exist
```

I had no better luck with `ssh` or `sftp`.

Is there a way to redirect output of a process from one system to a file on another remote lsystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple:

```
cat .profile | ssh qazwart@server2 "cat > ~/.profile"
```

The remote SSH command will take as `stdin` whatever you pipe from your local machine. You can do this with any other command, too. See some examples on [this blog post](http://scratching.psybermonkey.net/2011/02/ssh-how-to-pipe-output-from-local-to.html) and [this Unix & Linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34273/can-i-pipe-stdout-on-one-server-to-stdin-on-another-server).

Comment: A dangerous example....

Comment: Of course, but it's what the OP wants to use.

Comment: Of course, `ssh`! It does take STDIN. @MariusMatutiae - Yup, this is dangerous, but it does show this is possible.